# React-Native button doesn't navigate to next page

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a login screen with react-native. My problem is that pressing Login button doesn't navigate to correct screen without reloading the test device. This means that I'm getting correct auth tokens from api, but the navigation doesnt't work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my login page:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button, View, AsyncStorage, Alert} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
//import Loading from '../common/Loading'
//import Navigation from '../common/navigation'
import { onSignIn, STORAGE_KEY } from '../common/auth';
import Logout from './logout.js'
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import SignedIn from '../navigation/SignedIn.js'
import logout from './logout.js'



export default class login extends Component {



  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',


    };
}
// funktio joka hoitaa apikutsun eli hakee apista tokenin joka vahvistaa kirjautumisen.
  loginUser() {
    const { email, password,} = this.state;
    //tähän myöhemmin virheiden käsittely
    return axios.post("https://*******.com/auth",{
        email: email,
        password: password
    })
    // apista saatu token annetaan arvoksi STORAGE_KEY:lle
    .then((response) =>  {
      return onSignIn(STORAGE_KEY, response.token);



    })

}

  render() {
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (

      <View>
            <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}
        placeholder="E-Mail"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password:text})}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        placeholder="Password"
      />

      <Button onPress={() => {
        this.loginUser().then(() => navigate('SignedIn'));
        }}
        style={styles.button}
        title="Login">
      </Button>
    </View>

)};

}
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
  });
```

Comment: I don't think the `axios` return another promise after you have used `then` well, you can try to return a new promise from your function. It will work. If you need help. Reply me.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing following in login function, pass `navigation` in login function while calling it from `onPress`.

```
loginUser(navigation) {
    const { email, password,} = this.state;
    //tähän myöhemmin virheiden käsittely
    axios.post("https://*******.com/auth",{
        email: email,
        password: password
    })
    // apista saatu token annetaan arvoksi STORAGE_KEY:lle
    .then((response) =>  {
      navigation.navigate('SignedIn');
      return onSignIn(STORAGE_KEY, response.token);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no using method on this.loginUser()
`this.loginUser().then(() => navigate('SignedIn'));`

Can you try this? it will work.

```
loginUser() {
    const { email, password,} = this.state;
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    //tähän myöhemmin virheiden käsittely
    return axios.post("https://*******.com/auth",{
        email: email,
        password: password
    })
    // apista saatu token annetaan arvoksi STORAGE_KEY:lle
    .then((response) =>  {
      return onSignIn(STORAGE_KEY, response.token);
    })
    .then(() => navigate('SignedIn'))
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I don't get any error message, but pressing login button still doesn't navigate to next page.